# Dealing with async closure in swift

Tags: ios, swift

I have a class with init function, which contains `URLSession.shared.dataTask(with URL)`
It gets some data, modifies it and I want it to be listed in TableView.
In TableView extension of ViewController class file when I am referring to my data object properties, these are all empty, because all code in the closure is running after TableView setup and functions (ex: numberOfRowsInSection).
I tried using `DispatchQueue.main.async` function but same effect.

Comment: After getting data, reload your tableView. `tableView.reloadData()`

Comment: How can I refer to `tableView` from data object?